# Custom continuous color map in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I have read some questions on this subject but I have been unable to find a specific answer to my question.

Let consider the image below:

[image: Color map example]

My goal is just to change the *limit colors* of the map, e.g. in this case the color map goes from dark red to dark blue, let's say I would like it to go from dark green to dark blue. Specifically, I would it to go from colors `#244162` to `#DCE6F1` (tonalities of blue) in the same continuous way as in the example above.

How is it possible to do this?

---

**[EDIT]**

I have tried the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as clr

some_matrix = ...
cmap = clr.LinearSegmentedColormap('custom blue', ['#244162','#DCE6F1'], N=256)
plt.matshow(some_matrix, cmap=cmap)
```

But I get the error message `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not unicode`.

Comment: Other than "read some questions", have you tried anything?  For example, have you looked for an existing colormap that would work or tried `LinearSegmentedColormap`?

Comment: Here are some specific examples in `matplotlib` documentation. 

http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html

Comment: I have tried some existing color maps but I would like to define a custom one to keep a uniform formatting throughout a document. I have tried to implement `LinearSegmentedColormap` with this code `cmap = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap('custom blue', ['#244162','#DCE6F1'], N=256)` but it hasn't worked.

Comment: @DaneelOlivaw put that information in the question itself, and describe exactly what "*it hasn't worked*" means. Did the cm not generate? Was it not the colors you were looking for? What happened?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[`LinearSegmentedColormap`](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.1/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap) doesn't take a list of colours, it takes the following argument:

> a dictionary with a red, green and blue entries. Each entry should be a list of x, y0, y1 tuples, forming rows in a table. Entries for alpha are optional.

So, you either need to define a dictionary as above, or in your case, I think you just want to use the [`LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list()`](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.1/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list) method:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as clr
import numpy as np

some_matrix = np.random.rand(10,10)

cmap = clr.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('custom blue', ['#244162','#DCE6F1'], N=256)

plt.matshow(some_matrix, cmap=cmap)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Ah brilliant! That's exactly what I wanted, I was missing the `.from_list`, thank you!

Comment: By far the quickest way I found to create gradient cmaps; thanks for sharing!