# Matplotlib: combine gradient colormap with listed colormap

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a DataFrame with values from (0, 1) (note that both numbers are NOT included) from some calculation.

Then, there are some missing values that I fill with 0.

I want to create the following colormap for the heatmap:

1. If data is missing (==0): white colors in the heatmap (only ONE white color).
2. If data is below threshold (eg. 0 < data < 0.5): light color (only ONE light color).
3. If data is above threshold: gradient colormap of red (or any other, does not matter) colors.

They key here is that I want to have exact gray and exact white colors for 1. and 2. I do not want any gradient between values below the treshold and values above the threshold.

I have seen this question for combining two colormaps: [Combining two matplotlib colormaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31051488/combining-two-matplotlib-colormaps), but I don't really understand where in that code it maps negative values to the distinct colormap, or how to make the second colormap non-gradient.

Data just for the purpose of example:

```
data = np.random.rand(10,10) * 2 - 1.3
data[data < 0] = 0
```

And `ListedColormap`:

```
cmap = colors.ListedColormap(['gray', 'white', 'red'])
bounds = [0, 0.0001, 0.1, 1.0]
norm = colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)

plt.pcolor(data, cmap=cmap)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

And what it gives me:

[image: example_heatmap]

Once again: I want the change red part of the heatmap to a gradient (and, ideally, colorbar should not have all the colors of the same size as now).

Thanks.

**Update:**

I have finally realized that it is possible to make with one colormap defined via `cdict` as in answer to this: [Create own colormap using matplotlib and plot color scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16834861/create-own-colormap-using-matplotlib-and-plot-color-scale).

However, I do not get at all what I expect.

I have this `cdict`:

```
cdict = {'red':   ((0.0,  1.0, 1.0),
                   (0.0001,  1.0, 1.0),
                   (lower_bound, 0.99, 0.99),
                   (threshold, 0.99, 0.99),
                   (threshold + 0.0001, 0.98, 0.98),
                   (upper_bound,  0.57, 0.57),
                   (upper_bound + 0.0001,  0.0, 0.0),
                   (1.0, 0.0, 0.0)),

         'green': ((0.0,  1.0, 1.0),
                   (0.0001, 1.0, 1.0),
                   (lower_bound, 0.92, 0.92),
                   (threshold, 0.92, 0.92),
                   (threshold + 0.0001, 0.63, 0.63),
                   (upper_bound,  0.0, 0.0),
                   (upper_bound + 0.0001,  0.0, 0.0),
                   (1.0, 0.0, 0.0)),

         'blue':  ((0.0,  1.0, 1.0),
                   (0.0001,  1.0, 1.0),
                   (lower_bound, 0.82, 0.82),
                   (threshold, 0.82, 0.82),
                   (threshold + 0.0001, 0.42, 0.42),
                   (upper_bound, 0.0, 0.0),
                   (upper_bound + 0.0001,  0.0, 0.0),
                   (1.0, 0.0, 0.0))
        }
cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap('cdict', cdict)
```

Bounds:

```
lower_bound = data[data != 0].min()
upped_bound = data.max()
threshold = 0.2
```

Where for me `(lower_bound, upper_bound, threshold)` = `(0.02249988938707692, 0.6575927961263812, 0.2)`.

Plot:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (15, 6))
im = ax.imshow(data, cmap = cmap)
cbar = ax.figure.colorbar(im, ax = ax)
```

However, I get this:

[image: second_try]

How is it possible? Why do I have so many black squares if black color, from my understanding of `cdict`, is assigned only to values that are above `upper_bound`, which does not make sense since `upper_bound` is maximum of all array...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37401872/custom-continuous-color-map-in-matplotlib

Comment: @Ardweaden improved something based on the answers to the other question(s), but the issue is still not solved.

Comment: I think you set up your cdict incorrectly. Can you try the one I posted in the answer (posted there for convenience)?

Comment: @Ardweaden I tried but that is not what I expect. The colorbar should be the following: white around 0, light till 0.2, gradient from 0.2 to the end. What yours gave: black around 0, gradient till ~1.5, white after.

Comment: Can you either post an image of what you get *or* your data? That would be very helpful.

Comment: There is code that generates this data in the question (`data = np.random.rand(10,10) * 2 - 1.3` and `data[data < 0] = 0`).

Comment: I think I know the issue: matplotlib normalizes this data to correspond to [0, 1] region instead of [0, 63], which shifts the colorbar (I still don't know how to fix it though).

Comment: What you say in the comments "*white around 0, light till 0.2, gradient from 0.2 to the end*", is totally different from what the question text says.

Answer (score 1):

You want white from 0 to a threshhold, and a gradient from threshold to 1. When your data is in the range between 0 and 1 as well, this is pretty easy. The color for values below 0 can be set via `.set_under`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap


data = np.random.rand(10,10) * 2 - 1.3

thresh = 0.2
nodes = [0,thresh, thresh, 1.0]
colors = ["white", "white", "red", "indigo"]
cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("", list(zip(nodes, colors)))
cmap.set_under("gray")

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(data, cmap=cmap, vmin=0, vmax=1)
fig.colorbar(im, extend="min")
plt.show()
```

[image]